# How do I edit text as one of the layers, using GIMP

Tags: gimp, graphics-editing

I have a PSD and I want to edit text which is one of the "layers". Can I edit the text or do I have to create a new layer and delete the existing one.

Comment: Wait, GIMP? GNU Image Manipulation? This is not coding AFAIK. I'd vote to close, but I lost my rep in bounties.

Comment: FYI the [GIMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gimp) tag is not new and it actually have 87 associated questions -- none of them seem closed by 'not coding'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how that text layer has been saved: basically if you can select it with the Text Tool and it becomes editable, then you will be able to change it, otherwise you might need to create a new one. Hope it helps!